# Adding Outlook Contacts From Python

Tags: python, outlook

Like the title says I want to add contacts to Outlook using Python. Currently I am using `win32com` and can get all current contacts and print them out like so:

```
import win32com.client
import pywintypes

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = o.GetNamespace("MAPI")

contactsFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(10)
contacts = contactsFolder.Items

for c in contacts:
    print(c)
```

However, I am uncertain on how to add new contacts. Any ideas on how this can be achieved? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Final solution

```
ContactItem = contactsFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Contact")
ContactItem.FullName = "John Doe"
ContactItem.Email1Address = "someone@example.com" 
ContactItem.Save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `contactFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Contact")` - it will return an instance of the [ContactItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem) object. Set its properties and call `ContactItem.Save`.

Comment: You're a genius! If anyone else is reading this I've updated my answer to reflect the expanded final solution. **Last quick question**, is there a way to show the contact once it has been created?

Comment: **Second edit** to answer my own question from the comment above: to show the contact prior to saving use `ContactItem.Display(True)`